# Regarding : Random native exception from .NET Compact Framework 3.5 application - ES400 Specifics

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5, motorola-emdk

Came across the question [Random native exception from .NET Compact Framework 3.5 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518539/random-native-exception-from-net-compact-framework-3-5-application) and have an identical crash dump for an ES400, but the solution is rather vague and I need clarification regarding the solution specifics and effect of the latest firmware update on the Motorola ES400 device released as of the 15th Jan 2013.

To summarise the issue, a compact framework 3.5 application running on a Motorola ES400 is throwing occasional and, so far, un-recreateable, access violations at odd intervals.  I can post the crash dump which is rather light on useful information and is identical to those found against the original question, the answer to which seemed to be to do with system state information monitoring and ui updating, but was rather unspecific.

My question is, what system state information/control manipulation is relevant to this known issue? Does it make any difference to the solution if the latest firmware release as of 15th Jan 2013 is installed?

Apologies to anyone upset at this being posted as a whole new question but I cannot comment on the original as I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: Place everything in `try...catch` blocks until you narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks all, for the replies.  The whole program is in a try catch but does not catch this exception, I do not believe that I can catch an access violation exception in this way.  Worse, it does not seem to occur when running through the debugger (although it does seem to occur at random intervals so maybe I just haven't got lucky yet).  I was hoping any knowledge about the ES400 devices like that from the previous question I mention might be the idea spark I need.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can wrap all calls in question with try..catch blocks, that will cost resources and performance. It is always better to avoid exceptions.
*For example: you need to call a webservice: you can just put a try/catch around the webservice call but you can also ensure previously, if the webservice hosting server is reachable.*

As a first try you may only wrap the main form invocation in program.cs within try (Exception ex) ..catch. Unhandled exception will be handled in a tree like way and bubble from top to bottom until they are handled (sorry for my english).
Use all informations you can get from Exception class: Message, StackTrace,InnerException etc...
Possibly write these information to a file, so you can look at it later.

Some Native Exceptions cannot be catched. I have see such in conjunction with barcode reader objects or other device specific .NET wrapper objects. The only fix to such bad objects can be made by the programmers of the wrapper and the native code/DLL they use. For example: itcscan.dll is a C DLL to access a barcode reader, DataCollection.cf2.DLL is a .NET wrapper to this itcscan.dll. If there is a native exception in itcscan.dll, that may crash the .NET wrapper DLL and your application. You will not be able to fix that yourself. You have to ask the vendor for a new native and or .NET DLL.

### How to find the source of the native exception?

Just go thru your code and think about disabling the one or other call and test.
Have a good logging to a file, where all function calls and results are written down. Possibly you find a pattern in the log at which the native exception is thrown.
Re-think about how a function could be achieved. As in the post you mention, the author changed his code from an event driven status update of icons to a periodic time based check.

Comment: What is your preferred method for checking to see if a host is reachable, Josef? Ping?

Comment: Yes, a simple ping is the first try to check for a host.